# SUMPRODUCT over range that includes errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would you go about modifying this formula to allow for errors in column C?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C$4:C$45)*(ROUNDUP(MONTH($B$4:$B$45)/3,0)=VALUE(LEFT($B48,1)))*(YEAR($B$4:$B$45)=VALUE(RIGHT($B48,2))+2000))/3
```

Columns are following format:

```
AUG-14 =NA()
SEP-14 =NA()
OCT-14 102.45
NOV-14 103.11
DEC-14 104.23
JAN-15 =NA()
```

This formula calculates a quarterly average beased on the label held in B48, for example 3Q14.

Tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(C$4:C$45),(ROUNDUP(MONTH($B$4:$B$45)/3,0)=VALUE(LEFT($B48,1)))*(YEAR($B$4:$B$45)=VALUE(RIGHT($B48,2))+2000))/3
```

This doesn't work

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of that one, and the method shown there does not seem to apply to this particular formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where would the errors be? (I know you say column C but I mean in which rows?).

You could use `AVERAGEIFS` (requires Excel 2007 or later) which would ignore errors **except those in the relevant quarter**, i.e.

`=AVERAGEIFS(C$4:C$45,B$4:B$45,">="&DATE(100+RIGHT($B48,2),LEFT(B48)*3-2,1),B$4:B$45,"<"&DATE(100+RIGHT(B48,2),LEFT($B48)*3+1,1))`

If you might have errors, even on the relevant quarter, then try this "array formula"

`=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(C$4:C$45),IF(INT((MONTH(B$4:B$45)+2)/3)&"Q"&TEXT(B$4:B$45,"yy")=$B48,C$4:C$45)))`

that latter formula needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If there are no qualifying dates then you get `#DIV/0!` error. You can hide that by wrapping the whole formula in an `IFERROR` function

Answer (score 0):

Based on this very similar question:
[How do I sum a named range of values that contains errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739855/how-do-i-sum-a-named-range-of-values-that-contains-errors)

I think the following should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(((C$4:C$45)*(ROUNDUP(MONTH($B$4:$B$45)/3,0)=VALUE(LEFT($B48,1)))*(YEAR($B$4:$B$45)=VALUE(RIGHT($B48,2))+2000))/3)
```